# How to check if task<List<userMethod>> is empty

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

`App.Database.query(UserName.Text, Password.Text)` return listAsync but even there is no user is displayed YES !!

```
private async void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(App.Database.query(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text) == null )
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", " No user", "OK");
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Yes user", "OK");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `App.Database.query(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)` return?  Clearly it's not `null`.

Comment: even when its seems to be null , is not null

Comment: Something either is `null` or isn't.  How does it *seem* to be `null`?

Comment: has no value in that table

Comment: Your `== null` check isn't looking at a "table".  It's looking at whatever `App.Database.query(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text)` returns.  When you debug, *what does it return*?  (Hint: It's *not `null`*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is return `Task<IList<T>>`, and `async`, you will need to await it and check for empty list.

```
...
var users = await App.Database.query(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);
if(!users.Any())
...
```